# how to attach a file so it generates into a url?

Tags: php, javascript, forms, file-upload

I made this other thread a little while ago and one of the problems was solved which is uploading the image and converting it into a url. Unfortunately it only works for images not files so I wanted to ask on here if someone knew a way to upload files on a form so that the file is automatically generated into a url that a user can view by pasting into their address bar.

[how to make file or image attachment like SO on a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196582/how-to-make-file-or-image-attachment-like-so-on-a-form/7196709#7196709)

If there is a script I could make in the backend that uploads the pics to my webhost folder and view using that url, wouldn't be a bad idea....what do you think?

Any ideas on what to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to do the thing with images(they're files) you should be fine with about any file as long as you modify your code which should be hardcoded to accept only images.

Comment: You should however take care of people not being able to upload PHP (and other executable) files.

Comment: I will disable people uploading executable. That imgur only lets you upload images nothing else..